# What's the Emacs package that enables a "mini-mini-map" in the status bar?

Tags: spacemacs, minimap

I'm specifically talking about the package Spacemacs enables. It creates a tiny square with a horizontal bar, that goes up and down in accordance with your position in the file you have opened. E.g., if you're halfway down the file, the bar would be in the middle of the square.

Also, there's a number beside the square, with a percentage, giving you what percent down the file you are. So, in the above scenario, it'd say 50%.

Does anyone know what this package is, or how to enable this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package is called spaceline. It can be installed via melpa.

https://github.com/TheBB/spaceline

Comment: Thank you! Which segment, however, enables the "mini-map" feature (the bar that slides downward depending on your position)? It's not enabled by default.

Comment: @remacs spaceline's REDME mentions the feature as "hud: shows the currently visible part of the buffer.", it's provided by powerline.el.

Comment: @xuchunyang Awesome. Thank you.